# CodeIgniter is not storing session after payment redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, session-cookies, php-7

I am using Codeigniter 3.1.6 and when I redirect from payment I destroy my session. Even I call controller success with just hello world but still not working. Below is my session detail:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'None');
$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '';
$config['cookie_secure']    = TRUE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

I am using PHP 7.1 I even change PHP version as well but still same issue. Also added session start in index.php files but issue remain same. It happen only when it redirect from payment server after transaction or cancel transaction.  I checked session status its show that session start is working but other session which contain login user detail and cart data empty.

Comment: Where is your redirect code ? and where your controller success ?

Comment: There is a lot of debugging detail you did not mention, please check and update your question with details.  Does your `ci_sessions` table exist? Are there records in it? Are they being updated as you log in/out, etc?  Does the redirect from payment server come to an https page?  Is there a reason `cookie_path` is blank, instead of the default `/`?

Comment: Also: consider updating to CI 3.1.11 as it has fixed some issues with the session library reported on earlier versions: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html#bug-fixes-for-3-1-11

Comment: yes ci_sessions table exist

Comment: are you using the CI cart library?